# Adding two sets gives error regarding required and provided types

Tags: java, java-17

I'm trying to combine two sets `a` and `b`:

```
Set<? extends Element> a = getSetA();
Set<? extends Element> b = getSetB();
Set<? extends Element> c = new HashSet<>(a);
c.addAll(b);
```

But I'm getting this error on last line:

```
Required type: Collection<? extends capture of ? extends Element>
Provided: Set<capture of ? extends Element>
```

Comment: note that `Set<? extends Element>`  does **not** mean "a Set that can hold an Element or a child of Element", that would be just `Set<Element>`. It indeed mean: "a Set for a type that is Element or a Set for a type that is a subclass of Element", for example a `Set<SubElement>` or a `Set<AnotherSubElement>` (sure it could also be a `Set<Element>`) - assuming `SubElement extends Element` and `AnotherSubElement extends Element` -> but we cannot add an `AnotherSubElement`  to a `Set<SubElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add elements to a `Set<? extends Element>`. See also [Producer Extends Consumer Super](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/5133585). `Set<? extends Element>` would be a "producer" of `Element`s.

There is absolutely no need to declare `c` as `Set<? extends Element>`. Its type can just be `Set<Element>`, then the `addAll` call is valid.

```
Set<? extends Element> a = getSetA();
Set<? extends Element> b = getSetB();

Set<Element> c = new HashSet<>(a);
c.addAll(b);
// if you really like Set<? extends Element>, feel free to:
Set<? extends Element> d = c;
```

Comment: You are right, but in my case I'm not the owner of `getSetA` and `getSetB` methods, and they have their return type declared like that

Comment: @thmasker I am saying you should change the type of `c`, *not* `a` or `b`. I am also not asking you to change the return type of `getSetA` or `getSetB`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering stems from the use of wildcards (`? extends Element`) in the generics of your sets. When you declare `Set<? extends Element>`, it means the set can hold elements of some unknown subtype of `Element`. This leads to restrictions on what you can do with such collections, particularly when it comes to adding elements or collections to them. The Java compiler does not allow adding to a collection with an unknown generic type because it cannot ensure type safety at compile time.

However, there's a way to achieve what you want by using a method with a bounded type parameter. This approach allows you to capture the wildcard type and use it to combine sets in a type-safe manner. Here's how you can do it:

```
public static <T extends Element> Set<T> combineSets(Set<? extends T> a, Set<? extends T> b) {
    Set<T> c = new HashSet<>(a);
    c.addAll(b);
    return c;
}
```

This method captures the wildcard type with `<T extends Element>` and uses `T` as the type for the new set `c`. This way, both sets `a` and `b` are considered to be of type `T`, and you can safely add all elements from both sets to set `c`. Here's how you might use this method:

```
Set<? extends Element> a = getSetA(); // Assuming this returns Set<? extends Element>
Set<? extends Element> b = getSetB(); // Assuming this returns Set<? extends Element>
Set<Element> c = combineSets(a, b);
```

Comment: If `getSetA` and `getSetB` return `Set<? extends Element>`, you cannot assign it to a variable of type `Set<Element>`.

Comment: The sentence _When you declare `Set<? extends Element>`, it means the set can hold elements of __any type that is a subclass of Element___ is highly misleading. I strongly suggest you edit this to: "When you declare ..., it means that the set can hold elements of __some unknown subtype of Element__`.